# Could not create graphics context error in automator

Tags: automator

I want to make rotation in many images but I have the error Could not create graphics context. (I have same error with jpg)

What's the reason for this?

[image]

Comment: That's a pretty old action - does it do the same thing with .jpg or .png?

Comment: [This question and answers here on AskDifferent](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/337530/automator-action-rotate-images-is-incredibly-memory-intensive) may give you some clues how to proceed.

Comment: @red_menace yes

Answer (score 0):

I've had similar problems and I believe it usually indicates that the image (or image collection) is too large for the Automator image processing function to handle. If you see this message, try it with small images and see if it works for them. That's not a solution, obviously, but at least it'll tell you whether that's the problem.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).